# Watchdog messages and string replacement

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, log-messages

Hello I would like to know which of the following ways (or some other) of logging messages is better and why.
I am writing lots of .install files since I create content types and fields programmatically and I often write statements as following:

```
$t = get_t();
watchdog('mymodule',$t('Field !field_name created.', array('!field_name' => $file_field_name)));
```

OR

```
$t = get_t();
watchdog('mymodule',$t('Field !field_name created.'), array('!field_name' => $file_field_name));
```

Note: in the first example I am doing string replacement in the $t function in the second in the watchdog() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
watchdog('mymodule', 'Field !field_name created.', array('!field_name' => $file_field_name));
```

`watchdog()` function will translate the string you pass as the second parameter. You shouldn't translate the message before passing it to the `watchdog()`.

Check out [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/88919/8623) for more information and references.

Or consult the following [document](https://www.drupal.org/node/323101) from Drupal's documentation.